# Cannot install php7.2-fpm on the latest Ubuntu "18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, fpm

It looks like PHP 7.2 now comes out of the box on Ubuntu 18.04 but there are 2 versions: 7.2.3-1ubuntu1(base) and 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1(security).

When I try run apt install php7.2-fpm I get:

```
# apt install php7.2-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-fpm : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.3-1ubuntu1) but 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

or alternatively:

```
# apt install php-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-fpm : Depends: php7.2-fpm but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I cannot install either of FPM versions.

**Note**:
1. I've run *apt update* to update the cache before.

```
# apt-cache search php7.2
php7.2 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.2-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.2-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.2-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.2-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.2-dev - Files for PHP7.2 module development
php7.2-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.2-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.2-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.2-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.2-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.2-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.2-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.2-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.2-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.2-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.2-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.2-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.2-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.2-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.2-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.2-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.2-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php-amqp - AMQP extension for PHP
php-apcu - APC User Cache for PHP
php-ds - PHP extension providing efficient data structures for PHP 7
php-gearman - PHP wrapper to libgearman
php-geoip - GeoIP module for PHP
php-gmagick - Provides a wrapper to the GraphicsMagick library
php-gnupg - PHP wrapper around the gpgme library
php-http - PECL HTTP module for PHP Extended HTTP Support
php-igbinary - igbinary PHP serializer
php-imagick - Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
php-libsodium - PHP wrapper for the Sodium cryptographic library
php-mailparse - Email message manipulation for PHP
php-memcache - memcache extension module for PHP
php-memcached - memcached extension module for PHP, uses libmemcached
php-mongodb - MongoDB driver for PHP
php-msgpack - PHP extension for interfacing with MessagePack
php-oauth - OAuth 1.0 consumer and provider extension
php-pinba - Pinba module for PHP
php-propro - propro module for PHP
php-ps - ps module for PHP
php-radius - radius client library for PHP
php-raphf - raphf module for PHP
php-redis - PHP extension for interfacing with Redis
php-rrd - PHP bindings to rrd tool system
php-sass - PHP bindings to libsass - fast, native Sass parsing in PHP
php-smbclient - PHP wrapper for libsmbclient
php-solr - PHP extension for communicating with Apache Solr server
php-ssh2 - Bindings for the libssh2 library
php-stomp - Streaming Text Oriented Messaging Protocol (STOMP) client module for PHP
php-tideways - Tideways PHP Profiler Extension
php-uploadprogress - file upload progress tracking extension for PHP
php-uuid - PHP UUID extension
php-xdebug - Xdebug Module for PHP
php-yac - YAC (Yet Another Cache) for PHP
php-yaml - YAML-1.1 parser and emitter for PHP
php-zmq - ZeroMQ messaging bindings for PHP
php7.2-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP
php7.2-bz2 - bzip2 module for PHP
php7.2-dba - DBA module for PHP
php7.2-enchant - Enchant module for PHP
php7.2-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.2-imap - IMAP module for PHP
php7.2-interbase - Interbase module for PHP
php7.2-intl - Internationalisation module for PHP
php7.2-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.2-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.2-sybase - Sybase module for PHP
php7.2-xsl - XSL module for PHP (dummy)
php7.2-zip - Zip module for PHP
```

*apt update && apt upgrade && apt-get -f install php7.2-fpm* didn't help.

Has someone come across this issue before?
To me it looks like a broken dependency. Please help to understand what's going wrong.

Thanks & Regards,
C

Comment: Please type `apt-cache search php7` and see what are the options.

Comment: Try this: sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade   
sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add missing repositories:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
```